Why isn't the rate of an elementary reaction expressed in activity?
Why don't chemists use $r_\ce{X}=\frac{\text{d}a_\ce{X}}{\text{d}t}$ where $a_\ce{X}$ is the chemical activity of species $\ce{X}$ and corresponding rate law for elementary reactions as $r=ka_1^{\alpha_1}a_2^{\alpha_2}a_3^{\alpha_3}$? This will ensure that unit of all rate constants for elementary reactions is $\ce{s^{-1}}$ 
I understand that it isn't practical to use in exeriments but similar is the situation for equilibrium constant $K_\text{eq}$, formally expressed in activities.

Because we want to know how much money we gained/lost, not how many hamburgers we can buy. The latter parameter is also important, but only secondary.

Because thermodynamics and kinetics are two very different things.
